# Как сделать бордер у текста?

Tags: html, css

Необходимо понять каким образом можно выполнить такую задумку, как представлено в скрине.
Текст сам прозрачный, а бордер его с цветом?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/FjaAO.png

Comment: https://codepen.io/tag/text-outline

Answer (score 1):

можно использовать CSS-свойства *text-stroke* и *color*, соответственно

```
<p style="text-stroke: 1px white; color: transparent;">Пример текста</p>
```

text-stroke: 1px white, чтобы создать белый контур вокруг текста, и color: transparent, чтобы сделать текст прозрачным